# Differences between 0..3 and [0, 1, 2].iter()

Tags: rust

I can do this for a range type:

```
(0..3).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

But I can't do the same for:

```
[0, 1, 2].iter().collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

With that I get:

```
 error: the trait `core::iter::FromIterator<&_>` is not implemented for the type `collections::vec::Vec<i32>` [E0277]
```

To avoid that error, I have to do:

```
[0, 1, 2].iter().map(|&x| x).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

Why is that so? I thought the two were a different way of doing the same thing.

Comment: By the way: you can use [`.cloned()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.cloned) on the second example instead of `.map(|&x| x)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're not the same thing.

The problem here is that the call to `iter` on the array produces an `Iterator` of `&i32`s.  In order to work on every possible array, it can't return elements by value, since not all types implement `Copy` and you can't partially move out of an array.  So, in order to collect into a `Vec<i32>`, you have to turn the `&i32`s into `i32`s by copying them.

The *other* way in which they're not the same: the range doesn't require there to be an array containing all elements somewhere.  So there's that, too.